# Adoption of Lean methods

Tags: agile, lean

Are there any studies on the adoption of agile methods based on [Lean principles](http://www.poppendieck.com/)?  Some of the stats I'm looking for:

1. How widely is Lean used?
2. In terms of Agile methods, how does the adoption of Lean compare with other Agile methodologies like Scrum, XP, etc?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about Lean in the context of Lean Manufacturing. Did you know that the Lean system was developed from the Toyota Production System?

In that regard there is an article detailing why the TPS works where other waste-elimination and productivity systems have failed. It's written by two folks from the Harvard Business Review.

[Link: http://www.slideshare.net/FerdinandGrah/decoding-the-dnaoftoyotaproductionsystem](http://twi-institute.com/pdfs/article_DecodingToyotaProductionSystem.pdf)

http://twi-institute.com/pdfs/article_DecodingToyotaProductionSystem.pdf (Dead)

If I remember correctly, the article identifies why the Lean system works better than other systems.

Comment: Sorry, but link is dead (

Comment: Are there any comparative studies on the impact of these methods on productivity when applied to software manufacturing?